# Что нужно сделать, чтобы имя установленной программы в Android отображалось кириллицей?

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, есть ли возможность собрать пакет APK для Android, чтобы после установки имя приложения отображалось по-русски, типа Яндекс.Такси и что для этого нужно сделать?

Comment: Да, можно. Что вы напишите в имени приложения то и будет отображаться. Покажите ваш `strings.xml` и в нём `app_name` тэг - в нём и надо указать название вам нужное

Comment: Сделайте ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, можно. Что вы напишите в имени приложения то и будет отображаться. В проекте есть `strings.xml` и в нём `app_name` тэг - в нём и надо указать название вам нужное.